# Making a Soft Access Point ESP8266 and read data by labview

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I made a soft access point with AT Command and using ESP8266 (ESP - 12 - F), Atmega32a and Codvision AVR programming. Then I Connected to this wifi Hot spot with Laptop and cominucate between labview and ESP8266 (ESP - 12 - F) properly. ESP device read analog amount of a sensor and Labview receives data and plot the histogram... . this was amazing but sample rate was too low and I could have 100  sample per second. Increasing baud rate between AVR and ESP module not be siginificante  changing the sample rate. So I want to Make exactly this Project with Arduino. I setup ESP in Soft Access Point, I connected to module with Labview, But I cant read/ write data between them.
My code is here and my problem is what commands can send/Receives data from ESP to Labview. data is a 4 digit number (ADC amount).  I read Official document  of WiFi librariy in Soft AP from Arduino website, but there is not clear command to send and receive data in this mode. can anyone help to finish this project?
I try to reach to 2 Mb speed cominucate between those.

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<WiFiClient.h>
#include<ESP8266WebServer.h>
/* Set these to your desired credentials. */
const char *ssid = "ESPap";
const char *password = "thereisnospoon";
ESP8266WebServer server(8080); // PORT DETERMINE

/* Just a little test message.  Go to http://192.168.4.1 in a web browser
connected to this access point to see it.
*/
void handleRoot() {
server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>You are connected</h1>");
}
void setup() {
delay(1000);
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
/* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
Serial.println(myIP);
//server.on("/", handleRoot);
server.on("/other", [](){
server.send(200, "text/plain", "Other URL");

});
server.begin();
Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: There are surely other useful tags you could add to this question.

Comment: Recommend me please those tags.